# SQL Server cast a number format to another format

Tags: sql-server

I have this number format (I have it as varchar in my table) 6.71307E+15 I want to convert it to this: 6713073544159400.

Is there a way I can do that in SQL Server, because currently I have to do it manually using Excel.

Comment: Don't store numbers that way in the first place. Use a data type designed to store numbers.

Answer (score 1):

This should give you the closest representation:

```
SELECT CONVERT(BIGINT, CONVERT(FLOAT, '6.71307E+15'));
```

Even excel should only result *6713070000000000*